# Generics in Typescript: Passing generics in Functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My typescript code like below: (within typescript 4.4)

```js
export function convert<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
    func: T
): (_this: ThisParameterType<T>, ...args: OmitThisParameter<Parameters<T>>) => ReturnType<T> {
    return Function.call.bind(
        Function.bind,
        Function.call
    )(func) as (_this: ThisParameterType<T>, ...args: OmitThisParameter<Parameters<T>>) => ReturnType<T>;
}
```

but when i use it like this:

```js
// mark 1
const arrayShift = convert([].shift);
// expect: const shifted: string
const shifted = arrayShift(["1"]); // const shifted: undefined

// mark 2
const arrayMap = convert([].map);
// expect (parameter) e: string
arrayMap(["1"], (e) => { // (parameter) e: never
    return parseInt(e, 10);
});
```

How to got expected type with modify the function named 'convert'?

Comment: `shifted` is `undefined` because TypeScript knows that `[]` is empty, and so `[].shift` will return `undefined`. But I don't know how to solve it. I suspect it will be...complicated... :-)

Comment: When I change the code to 
`const arrayShift = convert(Array.prototype.shift);`
it cannot also works.

Comment: You basically want to write a generic function (`convert`) that returns a generic function (`result`) that infers its types when it's called (not from the types applied to `convert`). I have no idea how you do that, if you can. It's an interesting question.

Comment: `convert` (given what you want it to do above) is always a generic function. If you want `shifted` to be of type `string` and you don't want to use something like `const arrayShift = convert(([] as string[]).shift);` (which means the result will only work with string arrays), what it returns will also need to be generic.

Comment: You can write `convert()` to do what you want like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqQq2m), using the limited support for [higher order type inference from generic functions](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions), but there's no way to automatically turn `[].shift` or `[].map` into something useful to map into it.  The problem is that there's no higher kinded types or `forall` type quantifier in TS (see [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/62724646/2887218)) to get `[].map as forall T. Array<T>["map"]`

Comment: Meaning unless the compiler already knows that the parameter `f` to `convert(f)` is generic in the type of its `this` parameter, you have to spell it out manually, which probably defeats the purpose of this whole thing.  To reiterate: the problem is not really with `convert()` but with what happens if you try to peel a method off a generic class and inspect it.  I'm happy to write this up as an answer unless you think I'm missing something about your question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve it with a 2-step approach. The `convert` returns a function, which you can call, with or without arguments.

[see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=73&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBA3ApgJygHgIKLoAeU6YAJgM6J6aYCGAnjgCoB8ANIi4SWVYnphGXANK9SFagGt0jOMBp0mrNmwAUAWABQiQcsYAuGhP7VaDZjDDAsiAKptEAfiWWcjxMYsr2HHXqyRoii-toAlIgA3gGIoJCwCMhoWFA+zATEkgLpqlw8WWaCwhqxevQG3qZSbirWtpgOTq65nt4GeWWIQcahsZExunqImOhQIJhIFZYA2kEAurEAvrGj45Nx4NDwYDgAytU5HQCanIjHh9RCjKVDepQgAEYAVujQ6OTpxgeFNbn1dj2omatWYQKc7XcpzCw30AHNKM5jNcZvNEAB6dGIMBwKCIRhjOIwOETD6IOAgPFQODIegAGzpyTAGGw6UQAHcYFAABbwq4UbrodAAB0QUEYwvQlH60S6awmSHUKGZqVyey4py0d2GDxeb1InwMMNhgsYXXC4WWOhW2h0ysoeOmTD23JgwDxAF4mSyoOpUVwAOSUV3ugOW7T2x0GACy9FFXuVPr980DAFs42GdHaEA7CKnheLEF6nYwXW7fajwupIpimbn0PnxcZwOR0MBrB9s2Bc8Hy2TiwYy+6-QAiACMACYAMwj+ZVmtYyOIXvuj7GB2YaxwxAAH0QLbbHfIXdz6eFkvIRf0lljwtHY9nVfQRacUQxWPUwoq9FTYywkXQdcoE3MA4VWMYFUQL9MEodAAEkwF9dAuDHAAGcIAG5rQXOs8TPC9jDAEBU0eLBUSzbRxUlRAAGEKivQY9DIOEO2MANJWAuA6QDXdEADOF6EoLiOwDa0TzxCAKkoYw6MwVEr3IiMczxBsC0YWTqAHSwh19SSYPnd9cLzNSNJk+i9wPdswE7bQgA)

```
function convert<A extends Array<T>, T extends any, K extends keyof Array<T>>(
  array: A extends Array<infer U> ? Array<U> : Array<T>,
  key: K,
) {
  function convertArray<A extends Array<T>, T extends any>(
    array: A extends Array<infer U> ? Array<U> : Array<T>,
    key: K,
  ) {
    return array[key]
  }
  return function<S extends Array<Y>, Y extends any>(
    subjectedArray: S extends Array<infer SK> ? Array<SK> : Array<Y>,
    args?: any[] // not yet figured out to call convertArray with args and keep types
  ) {
    return (convertArray<S, Y>(
      subjectedArray,
      key
    ))
  }
}

const arrayShift = convert([], 'shift')
const arrayMap = convert([], 'map')

const empty = arrayShift([])() // const empty: undefined
const shifted = arrayShift(["123"])() // const shifted: string | undefined
const mapped = arrayMap(["1"])(e => { // (parameter) e: string
  return parseInt(e, 10);
}) // const mapped: number[]

type Car = {
  engine: 'petrol' | 'gasoline'
}
const cars: Car[] = []
const emptyCars = arrayShift(cars)() // const emptyCars: Car | undefined
```